# Why does this not produce a nested array?

Tags: arrays, powershell

For example, when running `$x = 1..100 | % {$_, ($_ + 1)}`, I would expect this to happen:

```
PS X:\Folder> $x[0]
1
2
PS X:\Folder> (Compare-Object $x[0] (1,2) -SyncWindow 0).length -eq 0
True
```

However, *this happens*:

```
PS X:\Folder> $x[0]
1
PS X:\Folder> (Compare-Object $x[0] (1,2) -SyncWindow 0).Length -eq 0
False
```

Why is this, and how can it be avoided?

Comment: `$x = 1..100 | % {Write-Output -NoEnumerate $_, ($_ + 1)}`

Comment: Or `$x = 1..100 |% {,($_,($_ + 1))}` which is wrapping the output in a single array element